# SQL to dplyr translation - problem with summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to transalte SQL code to R using dplyr library.

My current solution returns proper number of rows (I check it with the result that I obtain from sqldf function call). However there is a problem with the values which are returned and stored in **Votes** column which are much higher as they should be.

Comments about overall structure of the code would be also appreciated.

SQL:

```
SELECT
  PostId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN VoteDate = 'new' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) NewVotes, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN VoteDate = 'old' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) OldVotes, 
  SUM(Total) AS Votes
FROM ( 
    SELECT
      PostId,
      CASE STRFTIME('%Y', CreationDate)
        WHEN '2021' THEN 'new' 
        WHEN '2020' THEN 'new' 
        ELSE 'old'
        END VoteDate,
      COUNT(*) AS Total 
    FROM Votes
    WHERE VoteTypeId IN (1, 2, 5)
    GROUP BY PostId, VoteDate 
) AS VotesByAge
GROUP BY VotesByAge.PostId
HAVING NewVotes=0
```

dplyr:

```
Votes %>% filter(VoteTypeId %in% c(1,2,5)) %>% 
group_by(PostId, VoteDate = case_when(year(CreationDate) == 2021 | year(CreationDate) == 2020 ~ "new", TRUE ~ "old")) %>% 
mutate(Total = n()) %>% select(PostId, VoteDate, Total) %>% 
group_by(PostId) %>% 
mutate(NewVotes = max(case_when(VoteDate == "new" ~ as.integer(Total), TRUE ~ as.integer(0)))) %>% 
mutate(OldVotes = max(case_when(VoteDate == "old" ~ as.integer(Total), TRUE ~ as.integer(0)))) %>% 
filter(NewVotes == 0) %>% group_by(PostId, NewVotes, OldVotes) %>%
summarise(Votes = sum(Total))
```

I use data from https://archive.org/details/stackexchange (reduced in size)

```
structure(list(Id = 1:20, PostId = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
7L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 16L), VoteTypeId = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 2L), CreationDate = c("2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", 
"2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", 
"2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", 
"2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", 
"2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", 
"2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", 
"2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000", "2011-06-21T00:00:00.000"
), UserId = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 13L, 13L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30L, NA, NA), BountyAmount = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't have that data loaded, so just some comments: (1) Using `group_by(...)` *"to keep all the necessary columns"* is not the right approach. Group based on the variables you need to group by, and if you need to keep something from non-group variables, then that should be explicit (and likely aggregating in some way). (2) `year(CreationDate)==2021 | year(CreationDate)==2020,` can be way simplified to `year(CreationDate) %in% 2020:2021`. (2) The sample data you linked to appears to be XML files; if you have data then share it (`dput(x)`), please don't make use parse/combine.

Comment: (1) I will try to look for some way to do to that in a proper way. I have tried a few ways from other questions, but with no success at this point. (2) Thanks, seems much more simple to read and analyze. (3) I use CSV files, is there any nice way to share it with you? Using dput(x) on it returns weird results.

Comment: For (3) (aka my second `(2)` :-/ ), "it depends". One can include the first 20 or so rows of the raw CSV file in a code block in the question, and if reading it requires anything other than `read.csv(.)`, then include your `read.csv(...)` code as well. If there is any processing after import that is not obvious, though, it's usually better just to use `dput(x)` and paste the output into a code block. (Personally I prefer a one-line `structure(...)` as attained with `cat(deparse1(x),"\n")` with a suitably not-big `x`.)

Comment: I have added 20 first rows of data to the question. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface: I wasn't too sure what all your requirements were since you did not thoroughly explain the parameters using English and only showed your SQL code. I have made my solution based on the outcome of your SQL query and matched the R code to give the same output.

In the future, it would be more convenient if you could post a dput() of your desired_outcome as a dataframe and list all your requirements using words instead of code.

TLDR; You had duplicate rows. The distinct() function takes care of that.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(sqldf) #I used sqldf package to see your desired SQL output in R

#R solution
Votes %>% 
  filter(VoteTypeId %in% c(1,2,5)) %>% 
  group_by(PostId, VoteDate = case_when(year(CreationDate) == 2021 | year(CreationDate) == 2020 ~ "new", TRUE ~ "old")) %>% 
  select(-Id, -VoteTypeId, - CreationDate, -UserId, -BountyAmount) %>%
  mutate(Total = n()) %>% 
  distinct()  %>% 
  group_by(PostId) %>% 
  mutate(NewVotes = max(case_when(VoteDate == "new" ~ as.integer(Total), TRUE ~ as.integer(0)))) %>% 
  mutate(OldVotes = max(case_when(VoteDate == "old" ~ as.integer(Total), TRUE ~ as.integer(0)))) %>% 
  filter(NewVotes == 0) %>% group_by(PostId, NewVotes, OldVotes) %>%
  summarise(Votes = sum(Total))

   PostId NewVotes OldVotes Votes
    <int>    <int>    <int> <int>
 1      1        0        3     3
 2      2        0        5     5
 3      3        0        4     4
 4      5        0        1     1
 5      6        0        1     1
 6      7        0        2     2
 7      9        0        1     1
 8     11        0        1     1
 9     12        0        1     1
10     16        0        1     1
```

```
#Code to look at and understand your desired SQL output
query <- "SELECT
PostId,
MAX(CASE WHEN VoteDate = 'new' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) NewVotes, 
MAX(CASE WHEN VoteDate = 'old' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) OldVotes, 
SUM(Total) AS Votes
FROM ( 
  SELECT
  PostId,
  CASE STRFTIME('%Y', CreationDate)
  WHEN '2021' THEN 'new' 
  WHEN '2020' THEN 'new' 
  ELSE 'old'
  END VoteDate,
  COUNT(*) AS Total 
  FROM Votes
  WHERE VoteTypeId IN (1, 2, 5)
  GROUP BY PostId, VoteDate 
) AS VotesByAge
GROUP BY VotesByAge.PostId
HAVING NewVotes=0"

sqldf(query)

   PostId NewVotes OldVotes Votes
1       1        0        3     3
2       2        0        5     5
3       3        0        4     4
4       5        0        1     1
5       6        0        1     1
6       7        0        2     2
7       9        0        1     1
8      11        0        1     1
9      12        0        1     1
10     16        0        1     1
```

```
#This is your SQL code from your FROM line
sqldf("SELECT
PostId,
CASE STRFTIME('%Y', CreationDate)
WHEN '2021' THEN 'new' 
WHEN '2020' THEN 'new' 
ELSE 'old'
END VoteDate,
COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM Votes
WHERE VoteTypeId IN (1, 2, 5)
GROUP BY PostId, VoteDate")

   PostId VoteDate Total
1       1      old     3
2       2      old     5
3       3      old     4
4       5      old     1
5       6      old     1
6       7      old     2
7       9      old     1
8      11      old     1
9      12      old     1
10     16      old     1

#Equivalent in R
Votes %>% 
  filter(VoteTypeId %in% c(1,2,5)) %>% 
  group_by(PostId, VoteDate = case_when(year(CreationDate) == 2021 | year(CreationDate) == 2020 ~ "new", TRUE ~ "old")) %>% 
  select(-Id, -VoteTypeId, - CreationDate, -UserId, -BountyAmount) %>%
  mutate(Total = n()) %>% 
  distinct()

   PostId VoteDate Total
    <int> <chr>    <int>
 1      1 old          3
 2      2 old          5
 3      3 old          4
 4      5 old          1
 5      7 old          2
 6      6 old          1
 7     11 old          1
 8      9 old          1
 9     12 old          1
10     16 old          1
```